# How to check if subprocess is polling, but not receiving data

Tags: python, subprocess, polling

I use `subprocess.popen` command to scan a frequency.

My programm receives data, but, I am having difficulties to detect *'the end of a message'*.

So, I am looking for the code how to check if the `.poll()` command is polling, but not receiving data.

As far as I have found with google, line should be '' when no data received, and just once, the program responded by printing several empty lines. Unfortunately, this was only once, but, that could be what I am looking for. Meaning, 2 or 3 empty lines will probably also indicate there is no data to be received.

```
multimon_ng = subprocess.Popen("rtl_fm -f 169.65M -M fm -s 22050 -p 43 -g 30 | multimon-ng -a FLEX -t raw -",
  stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr = open('error.txt', 'a'),
  shell = True)

while True:
  multimon_ng.poll()
line = multimon_ng.stdout.readline()
print(line)
```

How to check if subprocess is polling?

Answer (score 1):

If the process is still running, `poll()` will return `None`. Otherwise it will return the exit code. ([From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects))

However, I'm not sure that will help you here:

- If you want to wait until the process exits, just make a single call to `wait()` instead of using `poll()`.
- If you want to keep the program running and respond to multiple messages across its lifetime then you are going to need to know exactly what an "end of message" signal looks like, call `stdout.readline()` in a loop, and detect and handle that signal without exiting that loop.